# Issues in validating Image file passed through post request in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I want to validate 2 things in my django project:

1. Is the Image passed is valid Image or not (having proper extension, nonempty etc.)
2. I have a function `isCovering70p` which returns bool, depending on whether the object in the image is covering 70% area or not.
   Now I have to check this also before saving the data to the db. If the image posted by user fails any of these 2, `400` response code should be sent.

This is my models.py:

```
def user_image_dir_path(instance, filename):
    return f"uploads/users/{instance.email}/{filename}"


class UserDetail(models.Model):

    email = models.EmailField(max_length=80)
    registration_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image_path = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_image_dir_path)
    image_meta = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def filename(self):
        return os.path.basename(self.file.name)
```

This is my serializers.py:

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = UserDetail
        fields = ['full_name', 'email', 'org_id', 'image_path']
```

From the [DRF docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/), I understood that my #1 validation condition will be taken care by DRF/django.

But, how and where should I take care of #2 condition?

Also, I want to update my `image_meta` field based on `isCovering70p`. How and where should I put the logic for that update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way that you could solve this is with the validate method on the serializer

```
class UserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = UserDetail
        fields = ['full_name', 'email', 'org_id', 'image_path']  
    
    def validate(self, data):
        if not isCovering70p(data['image_path']):
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'image_path': 'image is not covering 70% of area')
        return data
```

You can just add a validate function to your serializer and raise a ValidationError if the data received is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The issue with this approach I faced was, `data['image_path']` is of type `class 'django.core.files.uploadedfile.InMemoryUploadedFile'`, whereas `isCovering70p` expects a file path, or numpy array. According to django docs, the file is saved when that model object is saved. So, cannot access it before saving it.

Comment: After tinkering around your solution for a while, I realized there doesn't seem any way for using my `isCovering70p` method as according to django and DRF docs, serialization occurs before saving, and hence Files uploaded remains in memory only. So I had to modify my `isCovering70p` to use the InMemory bytes instead of filepath / np array. While this will be in ideal way for many, It wasn't for me as I don't have access to 'isCovering70p' method, and had to write a wrapper around that, adding overhead.

Comment: I'm upvoting because this lead to some results, and if no better ideas come, I'll accept this. Thanks.